ASP.NET MVC web app on .NET 4.7.1 updated Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Nuget Update from 1.1.0 to 5.2.2/4.0.6
My ASP.NET MVC web app on .NET 4.7.1 updated Microsoft.Data.SqlClient Nuget package from 1.1.0 to 5.2.2.
I get this error:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
'A network-related or instance-specific error occurred while establishing a connection to SQL Server.
The server was not found or was not accessible.
Verify that the instance name is correct and that SQL Server is configured to allow remote connections.
(provider: HTTP Provider, error: 0 - )

If I update to 4.0.6, I get this error instead:

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlException:
A connection was successfully established with the server, but then an error occurred during the login process.
(provider: SSL Provider, error: 0 - The target principal name is incorrect.)

I tried adding
Trusted_Connection=True;TrustServerCertificate=True;Encrypt=False 

but I still get that error.
Please advise

Microsoft has been making a number of breaking changes to SQL Server drivers in recent years including General Availability of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.0 and General Availability of Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 5.0. What does SELECT @@VERSION report on SQL Server are you attempting to connect to?

Aside... Trusted_Connection=True isn't anything to do with connection encryption, it switches to Windows/Active Directory authentication (using the current process's authentication token) instead of SQL Logon authentication (with a username and password).

compare your existing connection string against "https://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server/" This provides a number of options for various setup scenarios. Chances are your connection string was originally set up for TCP using a machine name, or named pipes and the updated driver has changed the syntax. I recall running into issues with either (localdb) vs. localhost and the like. You likely just need to make a correction to the way the database server name/address/pipe is represented. Basically what works in SSMS usually works with .Net.

@AlwaysLearning
SELECT @@VERSION return this
Microsoft SQL Server 2022 (RTM-CU15) (KB5041321) - 16.0.4145.4 (X64)   Sep 19 2024 08:25:04   Copyright (C) 2022 Microsoft Corporation  Developer

My connection in web.config

Added additional property but it is not working


The app uses Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore 3.1.14 and could not migrate to latest since MVC Web app is .Net Framework 4.7.1
